# Making a UDP class which doesn't block an ESP8266 / Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, udp, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a need in my Arduino compatible project to listen on an ESP8266 to a specific UDP port and respond when an appropriate message is received, whilst doing other application stuff in the main program loop.

I want to abstract the UDP stuff into its own class, and this is where my question comes.

How do I let my class continue to listen, [read a UDP packet](http://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/udp-examples.html), and then call a send response method, without putting lots of code into the main program loop?

The interface for my class is:

```
#ifndef Discover_Me_h
#define Discover_Me_h

#include "Arduino.h"

class DiscoverMe
{
  public:
    DiscoverMe(); //Constructor
    listenForPacket();// listens for packet, if one arrives it calls respond()
    respond();//Responds to the host which sent the packet with some data
};

#endif
```

The main program has:

```
    #include "DiscoverMe.h"
include "Arduino.h"

DiscoverMe dm;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
 pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  dm.listenForPacket();
}

void loop() {
  // I WANT MY DiscoverMe class to still work when my program gets here

  int switchVar = 1;
  digitalWrite(ledPin, switchVar);
    delay(200);
    if (switchVar == 1) {
      switchVar = 0;
    } else {
      switchVar = 1;
    }
}
```

If I initalise and call my `DiscoverMe` object , and call `listenForPacket()` I have 2 questions:

1. How do I make the `UDP.begin()`(which will be in the listenForPacket() method) not block, allowing my program to reach its `loop()`?
2. If my program reaches it's loop, will the `DiscoverMe` listener continue to listen infinitely, if no, how do I make it behave as such? I guess I am asking, once `loop()` is hit, are the classes behaviours ignored, or do they run in separate threads?

Comment: @tobi303 `setup()` and `loop()` are part of the Arduino framework. And `boost::asio` is not available on Arduino.

Comment: @gre_gor just after writing my comment I remembered that there is this arduino framework. afaik it isnt even standard c++ and I wonder why there is no appropriate tag. Or does the arduino tag alone already imply the use of that framework?

Comment: Added more detail for @tobi303, please remove unnecessary down votes.

Comment: i dont know arduino, but i guess you have to spwan a thread that notifies the main loop via some flag when something arrived. not my down vote(s) btw

Comment: Then may I ask you to vote up? I don't think Arduino has a concept like threads. This is a class design question specific to the environment.

Comment: In the loop, you **will** have to check if a packet has arrived every time. That's how the UDP library works (`if(Udp.parsePacket() > 0)`). Design-wise, it would be best to make a `DiscoverMe::HandlePacket` function which will check if a packet is available, then act on it, and is called in every `loop` iteration. In the `setup` function, you may only bind your UDP client to a specific port. `Udp.begin()` will not block anyways.

Comment: @tobi303 There is an [tag:arduino-c++] tag, but most language specific Arduino questions could be answered as c++ (considering some limitations). And [tag:arduino-esp8266] tag is specifically for usage of Arduino core on an ESP8266. And yes, the Arduino tag should imply that Arduino framework is used. Arduino also has no threads.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was as per @maximilian:

In the loop, you will have to check if a packet has arrived every time. That's how the UDP library works (if(Udp.parsePacket() > 0)).

Design-wise, it would be best to make a DiscoverMe::HandlePacket function which will check if a packet is available, then act on it, and is called in every loop iteration. In the setup function, you may only bind your UDP client to a specific port. Udp.begin() will not block anyways.

This was implemented and I can confirm it works.

Long story short, libraries seem to require a method which will be called . during the main program loop, to touch base with the class and see if it needs to do any work.